# String array list to text view to display it

Tags: java, arrays, list

How can i string this array list to a text view so that i can use it on tts ? Tried many codes but didn't really work, i am really new to android studio so i might sound really new.
Below is my code for the array list !

```
private String getEmotion(RecognizeResult res) {
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scores scores = res.scores;

    list.add(scores.anger);
    list.add(scores.happiness);
    list.add(scores.contempt);
    list.add(scores.disgust);
    list.add(scores.sadness);
    list.add(scores.neutral);
    list.add(scores.surprise);
    list.add(scores.fear);

    //sort list
    Collections.sort(list);

    double maxNum = list.get(list.size()  -1);

    if(maxNum == scores.anger)
        return "Anger";
    else if(maxNum == scores.happiness)
        return "Happiness";
    else if(maxNum == scores.contempt)
        return "Contempt";
    else if(maxNum == scores.disgust)
       return "Disgust";
    else if(maxNum == scores.sadness)
        return "Sadness";
    else if(maxNum == scores.neutral)
        return"Neutral";
    else if(maxNum == scores.surprise)
        return "Surprise";
    else if(maxNum == scores.fear)
        return "Fear";
    else
        return "Can't Detect";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'string this array list to a text view so that i can use it on tts'? What is RecognizeResult? What is Scores?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you problem is incorrect double value comparison: `double == double` does not work correctly in general case; correct way to compare double is `Double.compare(double, double) == 0`.

I think your code will be working fine, if you replace all of operations like `maxNum == scores.anger` to `Double.compare(maxNum, scores.anger) == 0`.

Moreover, I could offer you one of the way how to simplify this code:

```
private static final class Data {
    double maxNum = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    String emotion = "Can't Detect";

    void applyMax(double score, String emotion) {
        if (Double.compare(score, maxNum) > 0) {
            maxNum = score;
            this.emotion = emotion;
        }
    }
}

private String getEmotion(RecognizeResult res) {
    Scores scores = res.scores;
    Data data = new Data();

    data.applyMax(scores.anger, "Anger");
    data.applyMax(scores.happiness, "Happiness");
    data.applyMax(scores.contempt, "Contempt");
    data.applyMax(scores.disgust, "Disgust");
    data.applyMax(scores.sadness, "Sadness");
    data.applyMax(scores.neutral, "Neutral");
    data.applyMax(scores.surprise, "Surprise");
    data.applyMax(scores.fear, "Fear");

    return data.emotion;
}
```